# How to get next value of Sequence dynamically in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sequence

I used to a SQL guy and trying my hands on Oracle front.

I am getting dynamic values of sequence in a variable. I like to fetch next value for that sequence object in some output variable. How to handle this in Oracle.

I wrote something same for SQL like this:

```
SET @v_SQLString = 'SELECT @v_new_seq = next value for '+@v_table_name
SET @v_ParmDefinition = '@v_new_seq NUMERIC(19) OUTPUT'

EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @v_SQLString,
    @v_ParmDefinition,
    @v_new_seq = @v_new_seq OUTPUT
```

Looking for something same in Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

My_Sequence_Name.NextVal - check [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php) and [here](http://psoug.org/reference/sequences.html). Psoug is a great site for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

I have found answer in same forum somewhere. Posting it here again so it can be useful to somebody.

```
v_lc_table_name NVARCHAR2(30);
v_new_id    NUMBER(19,0);

v_select := 'select '||v_lc_table_name||'.nextval from dual';
      execute immediate v_select into v_new_id;
```